# Numerical integration, dimensions do not agree despite use of .^ and .*

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-integration

I have an issue with Matlab integration. It tells me that there is an error about dimensions. However they do agree and operations are properly done using vectorized operators (.^  .* etc...). It is simple code yet I am stuck

```
A = 1:10;
B = 1:10;

K_fun = @(x) (x ./ sqrt((x + A.^2 ) .* (x + B.^2) .* (x + B.^2)) );
K = integral( K_fun, 0,Inf );
```

and here the error message in the command window:

```
Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in @(x)(x./sqrt((x+A.^2).*(x+B.^2).*(x+B.^2)))

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 84)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 89)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in PROVA_New_Drag3 (line 21)
K = integral( K_fun , 0 , Inf);
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It evaluates both your integration limits in a vector, so effectively your `x`in the function is [0 Inf], which is why the lengths don't agree.

You can set the 'ArrayValued' flag to true in the integral call

```
K = integral( K_fun, 0,Inf,'ArrayValued', true );
```

to get it to evaluate them separately.

I got another warning about a singularity but this is likely because you're using 0, infinity and division so it's related more to your function than the integration call. It might help to to sprinkle some `eps` around in `K_fun`.

UPDATE: Please see Troy's explanation of the singularity warning and note that `eps` won't actually help with that.

Comment: The warning is actually due to the long-run behavior of the integrand going as `x^-0.5`, which is a divergent improper integral in the infinite limit.

Comment: That makes sense. In which case `eps` won't help.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. There is this warning which, though not stopping, I really did not understand what is the problem about: what do you mean with sprinkle some eps ?

Comment: Sorry, poor phrasing. `eps` represents the 'epsilon' value, the smallest number representable by the machine/datatype. When you're doing numerical computations involving analytical models you sometimes get expressions which evaluate to a number that's so small it can't be represented, and it gets rounded to zero. This zero then propagates through successive calculations, causing spurious zeros or infinities. Adding `eps` to such results nudges them back into the representable number space. However as Troy notes that isn't the problem here!

Comment: The warning you get is due to the fact that as x tends to infinity its importance outweighs that of the A or B values, and your function approaches x/sqrt(x^3) = x.x^(-3/2) = x^-0.5 which as Troy notes is divergent. Matlab can handle these things fairly well usually, and it's a warning not an error but if you have any way of testing the results you should do, and if you can get your end results by a different route you might be able to avoid this altogether.